# Where to place the native messaging host manifest file in Mac OS X in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, opera, chrome-native-messaging

My native messaging host works on -

Windows - chrome and opera

Linux - chrome and opera

Mac OS X - chrome only

I tried placing the manifest file at multiple places but all in vain. I tried the following two locations:

```
/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/

$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts  (works for chrome only)
```

Comment: @RobW I am only having issue with Opera on Mac OS X

Comment: Try `/Library/Application Support/Chromium/NativeMessagingHosts/`

Comment: `/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts` *should* work. How do you know that it "does not work"? What errors do you get?